# I am unable to to understand following Perl code

Tags: perl

I have the following Perl code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

my @array = (  3, 4, 1, 4, 7, 7, 4, 1, 3, 8 );
my %unordered;
@unordered{@array} = undef;

foreach my $key (keys %unordered) {
print "Unordered: $key\n";
}

my %seen;
my @ordered;

foreach my $element (@array) {
  if (  not $seen{$element}++ ) {
    push @ordered, $element;
  }
}
```

In the last `foreach` code block, I am unable to understand this - in the first iteration, the expression `not $seen{$element}++` evaluate to not 0 - true - so the if block execute. In the second iteration the expression `not $seen{$element}++` should again evaluate to not 0 - true as the hash is empty. So, reading the scalar `$seen{$element}` will read 0 and not 0 will evaluate to true. So, the if block should execute again. But, the book says it stops after first iteration. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: What do you think `++` is doing here?

Comment: The hash `%seen` has the same keys as `%unordered` so can be used in the same way without building two hashes.

Answer (score 2):

In the second iteration the hash will no longer be empty, because the `++` operator will have put a `1` in there. In a third iteration the value will be `2` (which for the purposes of this program is the same as `1`, it just means "seen at least once before").

At the end of your program `%seen` will contain the number of times each entry appears in your list.

`if $a++` increments the value of `$a` (treating it as 0 if missing), and then returns the value before that increment to the comparison.

It is important to use the postfix operator, as `if ++$a` will not work here: It also places a `1` in your hash, but it returns the *modified* value (so `1` even for the first iteration).

Comment: In the second iteration, the $element will have values 2 in the foreach line. So $seen{$element} will be undef i.e. 0 again. And, if block should execute.

Comment: @RabinHalder, not true.  Only the `++` affects the contents of `%seen`, the `not` is only for the benefit of the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

The last foreach loop can be detailled as:

```
# loop on all elements of the array
foreach my $element (@array) {
    # if the current element haven't been seen yet
    if ( not exists $seen{$element} ) {
        # add current element into ordered array
        push @ordered, $element;
    }
    # Increment the number of time element have been seen
    $seen{$element}++;
}
```

At the end, `@ordered` will contain:

```
(3, 4, 1, 7, 8)
```

A better name should be `@unique` instead of `@ordered`.

`%seen` will contain:

```
(3 => 2, 4 => 3, 1 => 2, 7 => 2, 8 => 1)
```